# Overlapping last two rows of dynamically created Grid in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have created dynamically a Grid control with two columns and populate its Rows using data from the database in first column and a textbox control in the second column. But the last two rows of grid gets overlapped.
The following is my code snippet.

```
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        // Create the Grid
        Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
        DynamicGrid.Width = 400;
        DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        DynamicGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        DynamicGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue);

        //Adding columns to datagrid
        ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);

        // Add first column header
        TextBlock txtBlock1 = new TextBlock();
        txtBlock1.Text = "Particulars";
        txtBlock1.FontSize = 14;
        txtBlock1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txtBlock1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        txtBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        Grid.SetRow(txtBlock1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock1, 0);

        // Add second column header
        TextBlock txtBlock2 = new TextBlock();
        txtBlock2.Text = "Amount";
        txtBlock2.FontSize = 14;
        txtBlock2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        txtBlock2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        txtBlock2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        Grid.SetRow(txtBlock2, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock2, 1);

        //// Add column headers to the Grid
        DynamicGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock1);
        DynamicGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock2);

        RowDefinition gridRow;
        TextBlock par;
        TextBox amt;

        int i = 1;
        string pjt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //Display all the Particulars
        SqlCeConnection con;
        con = dbConnection();
        SqlCeCommand cmd;
        string sql = "select * from " + pjt;
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, con);
            SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int ordName = rdr.GetOrdinal("Name");

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string nam = rdr.GetString(ordName);
                gridRow = new RowDefinition();
                gridRow.Height = new GridLength(45);
                DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);

                par = new TextBlock();
                par.Text = nam;
                par.FontSize = 12;
                par.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                Grid.SetRow(par, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(par, 0);

                amt = new TextBox();
                amt.Height = 20;
                amt.Width = 190;
                amt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                Grid.SetRow(amt, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(amt, 1);

                DynamicGrid.Children.Add(par);
                DynamicGrid.Children.Add(amt);
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        }
        this.Content = DynamicGrid;
    }
```

I can't figure out why this overlapping occurs.
Please help me out.

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in code in WPF (REGARDLESS of dynamic stuff), that's what XAML is for. Learn MVVM. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow and I have no enough reputations to post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I just added code to clear the children, rowDefinition and columndefinition of grid before initializing with values.

Here i the code I used.

```
grid1.Children.Clear();
grid1.RowDefinitions.Clear();
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

//Adding columns to datagrid
ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);

// Add first column header
TextBlock txtBlock1 = new TextBlock();
txtBlock1.Text = "Particulars";
txtBlock1.FontSize = 14;
txtBlock1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
txtBlock1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
txtBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
Grid.SetRow(txtBlock1, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock1, 0);

// Add second column header
TextBlock txtBlock2 = new TextBlock();
txtBlock2.Text = "Amount";
txtBlock2.FontSize = 14;
txtBlock2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
txtBlock2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
txtBlock2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
Grid.SetRow(txtBlock2, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock2, 1);

//// Add column headers to the Grid
grid1.Children.Add(txtBlock1);
grid1.Children.Add(txtBlock2);

RowDefinition gridRow = new RowDefinition();
grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
TextBlock par;
TextBox amt;

int i = 1;
string pjt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();


//Display all the Particulars
SqlCeConnection con;
con = dbConnection();
SqlCeCommand cmd;
string sql = "select * from " + pjt;
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, con);
    SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int ordName = rdr.GetOrdinal("Name");

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        string nam = rdr.GetString(ordName);
        gridRow = new RowDefinition();
        gridRow.Height = new GridLength(45);
        grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);

        par = new TextBlock();
        par.Text = nam;
        par.FontSize = 12;
        par.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        Grid.SetRow(par, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(par, 0);

        amt = new TextBox();
        amt.Height = 20;
        amt.Width = 190;
        amt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Grid.SetRow(amt, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(amt, 1);

        grid1.Children.Add(par);
        grid1.Children.Add(amt);
        i++;
    }                   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
}
```

I placed a grid in the XAML file itself instead of creating dynamically. Then added rows and columns dynamically.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code is still fundamentally wrong. You should learn MVVM instead of doing this horrible bunch of unmaintainable code.